# How can I pass API parameters into my div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a movie API website. I have 20 movies displayed on one page, so when I click on a movie, it should show extended description of a movie in a div, like here:
https://entertainmenthub.netlify.app/

So I'm trying how I can do it, I have a big function which gets json data and uses it to display movies, but I don't know how to make it pass parameters into popup div.
The function:

```
trendingMovies = movies =>{
        movie_container.innerHTML = '';

        movies.forEach(movie => {
            img = IMG_URL + movie.poster_path;
            title = movie.title;
            rate = movie.vote_average;
            date = movie.release_date;
            tagline = movie.tagline;

            const movieEl = document.createElement('div');
            movieEl.classList.add('movie');
            movieEl.setAttribute("data-modal-target", ".popup");

            movieEl.innerHTML = 
            `<span class="rate">${rate}</span>
            <img src="${img}">
            <span class="movie_title">${title}</span>
            <span class="movie_date" style="text-align: left;">${tagline}</span>
            <span class="movie_date">${date}</span>
                `
            movie_container.appendChild(movieEl);
        });

        const popup = document.createElement('div');
        popup.classList.add('popup');
        popup.innerHTML = 
                `<div class="popup_left">
                <img src="img/dark_knight.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="popup_right">
                    <span class="text" id="popup_title">Movie Title</span>
                    <span class="text" id="popup_tagline">Tagline</span>
                    <div class="description">
                    </div>
                </div>
            <span data-close-button="close_button" class="close_popup"><i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                `;
        movie_container.appendChild(popup);
        let movief = document.querySelectorAll('[data-modal-target]');
        console.log(movief);
        movief.forEach(el =>{
            el.addEventListener('click', (e) =>{
                movies.forEach(movie =>{
                    let modal = document.querySelector(el.dataset.modalTarget)
                    modal.innerHTML = '';
                    img = movie.img;
                    title = movie.title;
                    tag = movie.tagline;
                    modal.innerHTML = 
                    `
                    <div class="popup_left">
                    <img src=${img}>
                </div>
                <div class="popup_right">
                        <span class="text" id="popup_title">${title}</span>
                        <span class="text" id="popup_tagline">${tag}</span>
                        <div class="description">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <span data-close-button="close_button" class="close_popup"><i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    `
                    openModal(modal);
                })
                let close = document.querySelectorAll('[data-close-button]');

                close.forEach(el =>{
                    el.addEventListener('click', () =>{
                        const modal = el.closest('.popup');
                        closeModal(modal);
                    })
                })
                })
        })

    
        function openModal(modal){
            if(modal == null) return
            modal.classList.add('active');
            overlay.classList.add('active');
        }

        function closeModal(modal){
            if(modal == null) return
            modal.classList.remove('active');
            overlay.classList.remove('active');
        }
    };
```

So trendingMovies accept movies as json data, and uses it to display movies. But I also want to pass this data to popup div, so it displays the data of movie which I clicked on.
I also added snippet so it should be more clear how it functions for now.

```js
window.onload = function(){
    const API_KEY = 'api_key=73b31f15b44a93f52789c751c34a5d7d';
    const BASE_URL = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3';
    const API_URL = '/discover/movie?' + API_KEY + '&sort_by=popularity.desc';
    const IMG_URL = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500';

    const url = BASE_URL + API_URL;
    const movie_container = document.getElementById('movie_container');
    const prev = document.getElementById('prev');
    const next = document.getElementById('next');
    const numbs = document.querySelectorAll('.numb');
    const genres = document.querySelectorAll('.genre');
    const popup = document.querySelector('.popup');
    const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');

    var lastUrl = '';
    var currentPage = 1;
    var nextPage = 2;
    var prevPage = 3;
    var totalPages = 100;


    fetchURL(url);


    function fetchURL(url){
        lastUrl = url;
        fetch(url)
        .then(console.log(url))
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data =>{
            trendingMovies(data.results);
            currentPage = data.page;
            nextPage = currentPage + 1;
            prevPage = currentPage - 1;
            totalPages = data.total_pages;
            lastPage = totalPages;
            
            if(currentPage <= 1){
                prev.classList.add('disabled');
                next.classList.remove('disabled');
            }
            else if(currentPage >= lastPage){
                prev.classList.remove('disabled');
                next.classList.add('disabled');
            }else{
                prev.classList.remove('disabled');
                next.classList.remove('disabled');
            }
        })
    }   

    trendingMovies = movies =>{
        movie_container.innerHTML = '';

        movies.forEach(movie => {
            img = IMG_URL + movie.poster_path;
            title = movie.title;
            rate = movie.vote_average;
            date = movie.release_date;
            tagline = movie.tagline;

            const movieEl = document.createElement('div');
            movieEl.classList.add('movie');
            movieEl.setAttribute("data-modal-target", ".popup");

            movieEl.innerHTML = 
            `<span class="rate">${rate}</span>
            <img src="${img}">
            <span class="movie_title">${title}</span>
            <span class="movie_date" style="text-align: left;">${tagline}</span>
            <span class="movie_date">${date}</span>
                `
            movie_container.appendChild(movieEl);
        });

        const popup = document.createElement('div');
        popup.classList.add('popup');
        popup.innerHTML = 
                `<div class="popup_left">
                <img src="img/dark_knight.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="popup_right">
                    <span class="text" id="popup_title">Movie Title</span>
                    <span class="text" id="popup_tagline">Tagline</span>
                    <div class="description">
                    </div>
                </div>
            <span data-close-button="close_button" class="close_popup"><i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                `;
        movie_container.appendChild(popup);
        let movief = document.querySelectorAll('[data-modal-target]');
        movief.forEach(el =>{
            el.addEventListener('click', (e) =>{
                movies.forEach(movie =>{
                    let modal = document.querySelector(el.dataset.modalTarget)
                    modal.innerHTML = '';
                    img = movie.img;
                    title = movie.title;
                    tag = movie.tagline;
                    modal.innerHTML = 
                    `
                    <div class="popup_left">
                    <img src=${img}>
                </div>
                <div class="popup_right">
                        <span class="text" id="popup_title">${title}</span>
                        <span class="text" id="popup_tagline">${tag}</span>
                        <div class="description">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <span data-close-button="close_button" class="close_popup"><i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    `
                    openModal(modal);
                })
                let close = document.querySelectorAll('[data-close-button]');

                close.forEach(el =>{
                    el.addEventListener('click', () =>{
                        const modal = el.closest('.popup');
                        closeModal(modal);
                    })
                })
                })
        })

    
        function openModal(modal){
            if(modal == null) return
            modal.classList.add('active');
            overlay.classList.add('active');
        }

        function closeModal(modal){
            if(modal == null) return
            modal.classList.remove('active');
            overlay.classList.remove('active');
        }

        
    }; 
     

    prev.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
            if(prevPage > 0){
                pageCall(prevPage);
            }
            let numb = document.querySelectorAll('.numb.active');
            numb.forEach(el =>{
                if(el.classList.contains('active')){
                    el.classList.remove('active');
                }
            })
    
            let li = document.querySelectorAll('li');
                li.forEach(element =>{
                    if(element.innerText == prevPage){
                        element.classList.toggle('active');
                    }
                })
        })

    next.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        if(nextPage <= totalPages){
            pageCall(nextPage);
        } 
        let numb = document.querySelectorAll('.numb.active');
        numb.forEach(el =>{
            if(el.classList.contains('active')){
                el.classList.remove('active');
            }
        })
        let li = document.querySelectorAll('li');
            li.forEach(element =>{
                if(element.innerText == nextPage){
                    element.classList.toggle('active');
                }
            })
    })

     function pageCall(page){
      let url = new URL(lastUrl)
      url.searchParams.set("page", page)      
      fetchURL(url);
      console.log(typeof(page));
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        } 

    numbs.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', (e) =>{
        if (e.target.classList.contains('active')) {
            e.target.classList.remove('active');
          } else if (!e.target.classList.contains('active')) {
            let numb = document.querySelectorAll('.numb.active');
            numb.forEach(num =>{
                if(num.classList.contains('active')){
                    num.classList.remove('active');
                }
            })
            e.target.classList.add('active');
          }
            pagination(e);
            }));

    genres.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if (e.target.classList.contains('active')) {
            e.target.classList.remove('active');
          } else if (!e.target.classList.contains('active')) {
            e.target.classList.toggle('active');
          }
          genreChoose(e);    
    }))

    function genreChoose(e){
        let genres = {
            'Action': '28',
            'Adventure': '12',
            'Animation': '16',
            'Comedy': '35',
            'Crime': '80',
            'Documentary': '99',
            'Drama': '18',
            'Family': '10751',
            'Fantasy': '14',
            'History': '36',
            'Horror': '27',
            'Music': '10402',
            'Mystery': '9648',
            'Romance': '10749',
            'Science_Fiction': '878',
            'TV_Movie': '10770',
            'Thriller': '53',
            'War': '10752',
            'Western': '37'
        };
        params = new URLSearchParams('');
        document.querySelectorAll('.genre.active').forEach(f => params.append('with_genres', genres[f.innerText]));
        console.log(params.toString());
        fetchURL(url + ([...params].length > 0 ? '&' : '') + params.toString());
    }

    function pagination(e) {
            pageCall(e.target.innerText);
        
        let dots = document.getElementsByClassName('dots')[0];
            let numb1 = document.getElementById('numb1');
            if (parseInt(e.target.innerText) >= 2) {
                numb1.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', dots);
            }       
      }

}
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    --primary-color: #39445a;
    --secondary-color: rgb(34, 24, 24);
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
}

.header{
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: "Montserrat",sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color:#fff;
    font-size: 3em;
    font-weight: 100;
    padding: 30px 0px 20px;
    width:100%;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 20px 6px rgb(20, 19, 19);
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
}
.header a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.app{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;  
    width:100%;
    min-height:100vh;
    background-color: var(--secondary-color);
}

.app h1{
    font-family: "Montserrat",sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color:#39445a;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: 900;
}

.movie_container{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.movie{
    cursor:pointer;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px 15px;
    background-color: #282c34;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family: "Montserrat",sans-serif;
}

.movie:hover{
    background-color: #fff;
}

.movie .movie_title{
    font-family: "Montserrat",sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color:#fff;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-align: center;
}

.movie:hover .movie_title{
    color:#282c34;
}

.movie .rate{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #3f51b5;
    height: 20px;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0 6px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    min-width: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: transform 225ms cubic-bezier(0.3, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: "Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1;
    align-content: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}

.spans{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.movie .movie_date{
    font-family: "Montserrat",sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color:rgb(189, 179, 179);
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-align: right;
}

.popup{
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
    transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
    border-radius: 10px;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    width:80%;
    max-width: 80%;
    height:80%;
    max-height: 90%;
}

.close_popup{
    align-self: flex-start;
    margin:20px;
}

.close_popup i{
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size:1.7rem;
}

.close_popup i:hover{
    color: #b5b8c0;
}

.popup.active{
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}

#overlay{
    position: fixed;
    opacity: 0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    pointer-events: none;
}

#overlay.active{
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
}

.popup_right{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content:first baseline;
    align-items: center;
    width:60%;
    height:80%;
}

#popup_title{
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:100;
}

#popup_tagline{
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-family: "Montserrat",sans-serif;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:200;
}

.description{
    display: flex;
    height: 40%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    scrollbar-width: thin;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #000;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-family: "Montserrat",sans-serif;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:100;
}

.text{
    margin:5px;
}

.popup_left{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin:30px;
    height:100%;
    width:100px;
}

.popup_left img{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    object-fit: contain;
}

.pagination{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.pagination ul{
    width: 30%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.pagination ul li{
    color: #fff;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.pagination ul li.numb{
    height:45px;
    width:45px;
}

.pagination ul li.btn{
    background: turquoise;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.pagination ul li.btn.disabled{
    cursor: not-allowed;
}

.pagination ul li.prev{
    border-radius: 25px 5px 5px 25px;
}

.pagination ul li.next{
    border-radius: 5px 25px 25px 5px;  
}

.pagination ul li.active,
.pagination ul li:hover,
.pagination ul li:active{
    background: #4d5f85;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.bottom_menu{
    width: 100%;
    height:70px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 70px;
    background-color: #2d313a;
}

.btn{
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.btn a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#fff;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.icon{
    color:#fff;
    text-align: center;
}

.icon_text{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#fff;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.genres{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin:10px;
}

.genres .genre{
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #fff;
    line-height: 3px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding:10px 15px;
    font-size: 0.850rem;
    margin:2px;
    font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.genres .genre.active{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #3f51b5;
}

.genres span.close{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: none;
    padding: 5px;
    line-height: 2px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-size: 0.850rem;
    color: #3f51b5;
    background-color: rgba(172, 157, 157, 0.7);
}

.search-container{
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.search-container input[type=text]{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 10px;
    width:700px;
    height:40px;
    border: 1px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    font-size: 17px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.09);
    color:#fff;
}


.search-container button{
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 13px 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 25px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.search_options{
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 23%;
}

.option{
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: transparent;
    color:#fff;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.75;
    white-space: normal;
    letter-spacing: 0.02857em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding:10px 30px;
    margin: 5px;
    background: linear-gradient(-90deg, #fff, rgb(116, 113, 113));
}

.option > span{
    position: absolute;
    background: gray;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f84da73aa8.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Movie Search</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    <div class="header">
        movie search
    </div>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>trending today</h1>
        <div class="movie_container" id="movie_container">
            <div class="popup" id="popup">
                <div class="popup_left">
                    <img src="img/dark_knight.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="popup_right">
                        <span class="text" id="popup_title">Movie Title</span>
                        <span class="text" id="popup_tagline">Tagline</span>
                        <div class="description">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <span data-close-button="close_button" class="close_popup"><i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            </div>
            <div class="movie" data-modal-target=".popup">
                <span class="rate">fuck</span>
                <img src="img/dark_knight.jpg">
                <span class="movie_title">the dark knight</span>
                <div class="spans">
                    <span class="movie_date">USA</span>
                     <span class="movie_date" style="text-align: left;">I'm Batman</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pagination">
            <ul id="pag">
                <li class="btn prev" id="prev"><span><i class="fas fa-angle-left">Prev</i></span></li>
                <li class="numb active" id="numb1"><span>1</span></li>
                <li class="numb"><span>2</span></li>
                <li class="numb"><span>3</span></li>
                <li class="numb"><span>4</span></li>
                <li class="numb" id="numb5"><span>5</span></li>
                <li class="dots"><span>...</span></li>
                <li class="numb"><span>10</span></li>
                <li class="btn next" id="next"><span>Next<i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom_menu">
            <div class="btn">            
                <span class="material-icons icon">whatshot</span>
                <span class="icon_text">trending</span>
            </div>
            <div class="btn">
                <span class="material-icons icon">movie</span>
                <span class="icon_text"><a href="movies.html">movies</a></span>
            </div>
            <div class="btn">
                <span class="material-icons icon">desktop_windows</span>
                <span class="icon_text">TV series</span>
            </div>
            <div class="btn">
                <span class="material-icons icon">search</span>
                <span class="icon_text"><a href="search.html">search</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well you could put the JSON data inside an invisible div and when the popup displays, [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check on click if the title of the clicked element matches that of the foreach loop element and append the data according to that.

See this working codepen for example: https://codepen.io/carve-the-looper/pen/KKXMwJJ

Specifics of what changed:

```
        let clicked_target = null;
        if (target.getAttribute("class") === null) {
          clicked_target = target.parentElement;
        } else {
          clicked_target = target;
        }
        let clicked_title = clicked_target.querySelector("span.movie_title")
          .textContent;
        movies.forEach((movie) => {
          // skip foreach if title doesnt match
          if (clicked_title === movie.title) {
             // use data from movie for modal
          }
```

Comment: it solved my problem, thank you so much!